# Unable to create dataset for image segmentation keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network, image-segmentation

I have a custom dataset that contains 1100 retina images across RGB channels and their corresponding grayscale masks with a resolution of 1500x1500. The job is to extract optic disc from those images. I have been trying to create training set from those images so that I can fit it into a u-net model. I have resized all the images into 256x256 resolution using opencv and created numpy arrays of those images. But when I fit this data into the model I am not getting accuracy greater than 1 no matter how many epochs I increased. I have also tried dice coefficient and loss function. They are also giving values greater than 1. I was wondering if the problem is in the training data creation or in the model.
Below is the code I am using for training set creation.

```
train_data='train_image_folder'
label_data="mask_image_folder"
def training():
    train_images=[]
    for i in tqdm(os.listdir(train_data)):
        path=os.path.join(train_data,i)
        img=cv2.imread(path,-1)
        img=cv2.resize(img,(256,256))
        train_images.append(np.array(img))
    return train_images
training_images=training()
train_data=np.array([training_images]).reshape(-1,256,256,3)
def label():
    label_images=[]
    for i in tqdm(os.listdir(label_data)):
        path=os.path.join(label_data,i)
        img=cv2.imread(path,0)
        img=cv2.resize(img,(256,256))
        label_images.append(np.array(img))
    return label_images
label_images=label()
label_data=np.array([label_images]).reshape(-1,256,256,1)
```

Below is the code for compiling and fitting.

```
model.compile(loss="binary_crossentropy", optimizer="adam", metrics=["accuracy","binary_crossentropy",dice_coef])
model.fit(train_data,label_data,epochs=50,batch_size=20)
```

And the corresponding dice coefficient function

```
def dice_coef(y_true, y_pred):
    y_true_f = K.flatten(y_true)
    y_pred_f = K.flatten(y_pred)
    intersection = K.sum(y_true_f * y_pred_f)
    return (2. * intersection + smooth) / (K.sum(y_true_f) + K.sum(y_pred_f) + smooth)
```

I don't know what I am doing wrong. Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Can I ask you to put your code (Created model)?
Are you test SGD or change learning rate ?

```
from keras.optimizers import Adam, SGD
...
...
model.compile(loss="categorical_crossentropy", # Change to categorical
optimizer=Adam(lr = .1), # For exam, or use SGD(lr = .1) and change learning rate and momentum
    metrics=["accuracy",dice_coef])
```

Please test this part code